# how find function in source

Tags: ssl, ssh, openssl, open-source

In researching how to best utilize OpenSSH, I looked into SHA hashing and found [a post discussing the SHA2 functions in OpenSSL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001893/when-should-i-use-sha-1-and-when-should-i-use-sha-2) The accepted answer states

> SHA-224 and SHA-256 are the same function, save for an internal parameter

I'm sure that this is true but, I'd like to take a look-see myself. Just so I know how it looks. Specifically, I'd like to look at the function that does the SHA-224 and SHA-256 hashing.

As an aside, this question important to me because I've taken a few intro to programming (C and perl) courses and these have always left me feeling like "OK, so what? How does this do something useful". Perhaps by poking around a bit I'll see what useful code looks like, learn a bit about how open source software is organized, and take a small step toward contributing to something useful myself.

So I downloaded [the OpenSSL source code (openssl-1.0.2e.tar.gz)](https://www.openssl.org/source/), unpacked it and thought "Wow, where do I start?"

So, um, where do I start? There are lots of files and lots of directories. Is there a convention for where things are put? Is there a development environment I should install that would help to see the bigger picture? Any help to get me started in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is a good start. useful keywords:

```
openssl sha256
```

Second result brings you to the header file [`openssl/sha.h`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/sha.html), where you find how are the functions called in the code:

```
 int SHA224_Init(SHA256_CTX *c);
 int SHA224_Update(SHA256_CTX *c, const void *data, size_t len);
 int SHA224_Final(unsigned char *md, SHA256_CTX *c);
 unsigned char *SHA224(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,
      unsigned char *md);

 int SHA256_Init(SHA256_CTX *c);
 int SHA256_Update(SHA256_CTX *c, const void *data, size_t len);
 int SHA256_Final(unsigned char *md, SHA256_CTX *c);
 unsigned char *SHA256(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,
      unsigned char *md);
```

And then is nothing easier then clone openssl git and grep through it, for example [github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) should be enough. Now, keyword `SHA256_Init`. And hooray, the implementation is [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/349807608f31b20af01a342d0072bb92e0b036e2/crypto/sha/sha256.c) in

```
openssl/crypto/sha/sha256.c
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the process. I'll duplicate that, Sounds like I might learn something by looking at what github is and how it works.